# Why do I get a 200 status code but then redirected back to the login page?

Tags: http, post, python-requests, http-post

I am trying to login to website using python requests library; I get the 200 status code however I just get redirected back to the login page.

I have tried many variations of the various post function variables including:

- `data = formData`, form data includes the correct `username`, `password` and `_csrf` token
- `data = json.dumps(formData)`
- `headers = headers` (which included the "user-agent")
- `auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username,password)` where `username` and `password` are the correct string variables for the site login

```py
with requests.Session() as c:
    loginPage = c.get(LoginURL)
    loggedInPage = c.post(LoginURL, 
                          data=formData,
                          headers=headers,
                          auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password)
                    )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get 401 Status code from post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092286/why-do-i-get-401-status-code-from-post-request)

Comment: Funnily enough these are not the same problem, I am having two different problems with two different websites!